# Image Map number display

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a image map, for example

```
<img  src="http://www.isdntek.com/tagbot/misc/bambi.jpg" usemap="#Map" class="mapp">

<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area class="map_circle" item="state1" target="" alt="1" title="1" href="#links" coords="223,541,62" shape="circle"  data-maphilight='{"alwaysOn":true,"stroke":false,"fillColor":"FFFFFF","fillOpacity":"1"}'>/>
    <area item="state2" target="" alt="2" title="2" href="#links" coords="75,274,NaN" shape="circle">
    <area item="state3" target="" alt="3" title="3" href="#links" coords="338,358,NaN" shape="circle">
    <area item="state4" target="" alt="4" title="4" href="#links" coords="595,414,NaN" shape="circle">
    <area item="state5" target="" alt="5" title="5" href="#links" coords="626,284,NaN" shape="circle">
    <area item="state6" target="" alt="6" title="6" href="#links" coords="707,342,NaN" shape="circle">
    <area item="state7" target="" alt="7" title="7" href="#links" coords="799,278,NaN" shape="circle">
</map>
```

I want it so that in these circles inside it was still displayed title, for example, 1,2,3,4 inside in my circle, now is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are omitting the `area` element `circle` coordinate radius (either on purpose or by mistake) which leads an undefined area.

You should fill all the `circle` `coords`:

```
<area item="state2" target="" alt="2" title="2" href="#links" coords="75,274,20" shape="circle"> <!-- 20 instead of NaN -->
```

Comment: yes, this has already been fixed, I need to display numbers from inside this circle ftom title

Comment: Titles will be displayed by default whenever you will be hovering on an area. You can accept the answer as it solves the main described issue and feel free to open another thread and I will be glad to help :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67647895/image-map-number-in-the-circle